# BoxLayout shows white line at bottom

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, gridbaglayout, boxlayout

I try to make multiple lines which fill the whole frame at vertical and horizontal. I tried it with a GridLayout with a GridBagLayout and now with the BoxLayout - the same problem ever! White lines by resizing...

I dont know which LayoutManager I should use, because all have the same problem! I want a responsive Layout so I need to use a LayoutManager and can't fix the elements. Can anybody help me?

```
    Container parentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
    parentPane.add(parentPanel);        

    parentPanel.setLayout( new javax.swing.BoxLayout(parentPanel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));   
    JPanel[] parentPanelFields = new JPanel[6];

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            parentPanelFields[i] = new JPanel();        
            parentPanelFields[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
            if(i != 5) parentPanelFields[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.WHITE));

            parentPanel.add (parentPanelFields[i]);

        }
```

The result of the code is perfect, but on resizing the frame a big white line fade in at the bottom of the frame...

Perfect result, but with a big bold line at the bottom:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r8HM.png]

This is my first question with the same problem, but with the GridBagLayout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384891/gridbaglayout-shows-white-lines-at-top-and-bottom?noredirect=1#comment58475366_35384891

How can I make these lines in Y-AXIS without these white lines by resizing the frame?

Please help me - I despair for 3 days with this problem...

A big thank you,
Waldi

**EDIT1: The whole code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test {

public static void addComponentsToPane(JFrame frame) {

    Container parentPane = frame.getContentPane();

    JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
    parentPane.add(parentPanel);        

    parentPanel.setLayout( new javax.swing.BoxLayout(parentPanel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));   
    JPanel[] parentPanelFields = new JPanel[6];

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            parentPanelFields[i] = new JPanel();        
            parentPanelFields[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
            if(i != 5) parentPanelFields[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.WHITE));

            parentPanel.add (parentPanelFields[i]);

        }

}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Source Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    addComponentsToPane(frame);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**EDIT2: The solution from camickr:**

First download the class RelativeLayout from https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/ (bottom of the page)

Second step is to write the code for your problem -> in my case:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.Y_AXIS);
    rl.setFill( true );
    JPanel somePanel = new JPanel();
    somePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    somePanel.setLayout( rl );


    JPanel blue = new JPanel();
    blue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    somePanel.add(blue, new Float(1));
    parentPane.add(somePanel);

    JPanel green = new JPanel();
    green.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    somePanel.add(green, new Float(1));
    parentPane.add(somePanel);

    JPanel red = new JPanel();
    red.setBackground(Color.RED);
    somePanel.add(red, new Float(1));
    parentPane.add(somePanel);
```

Use the RelativeLayout like other LayoutManagers!

Comment: Sounds like something with borders.

Comment: I dont use any borders. Even width .setBorder(0, 0, 0, 0) the white line is showing... Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you use `.setBorder()`? Have you tried using it on the frames, the panels and stuff as well? It might be something with the layout itself as well

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Without proper code we can only guess. Having said that, my guess is that you're artificially setting sizes or preferred sizes and not allowing the components of your GUI to adequately size itself. Please don't force us to guess -- post your [mcve] that we can run and evaluate (not a link -- code here with your question).

Comment: @Zizouz212 I've added these snippet to the parentPanel and the fields into the parentPanel, no result. I think these line isn't a border.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your answer. The code above is the whole code I have. These Code produce the problem... I post you the remaining code here, but this code only show the frame...

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the problem but rather produces a small GUI. Now if I resize the bugger with my mouse, I can reproduce your problem since by doing so, I make your GUi into a size that doesn't naturally fit all the components -- **and that is exactly what you're doing in code somewhere that you are still not showing us**.

Comment: Again, I will bet dollars to donuts that you're still setting the GUI's size or a component's size manually and are not showing us this code. Not sure why you're not showing it, but I'm sure it's there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hello again. I can't really follow you... The Code above I've added with "EDIT1" is the whole code. I haven't more code! When the frame is open all is okey, but if i resize the frame the white line at the bottom is showing.

Comment: Exactly! **If you resize the frame...** Don't resize it. Call pack, have it naturally size itself, and you should be fine.

Comment: I don't understand what you really mean :-( - I want a responsive Layout, "don't resize it" is no option for me... If i remove pack, the problem is also available...

Comment: @Waldi, `if i resize the frame...` - you didn't include "if I resize the frame **(with the mouse)**...". so hovercraft is thinking that somewhere in your code you have a `frame.setSize(...)` which is the cause of the problem. So he is suggesting don't use setSize(), but instead use pack() in the application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have 6 panels that are added to a frame and the frame is packed then each panel will display as expected.

If you increase the frame size by 5 pixels there is not enough space to give each panel an extra pixel so you have 5 extra pixels at the bottom as the layout manager does not know how to allocate these extra pixels to the components.

If you then expand the frame 1 more pixel then each panel will receive an extra pixel and the space will go away.

You could try using the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). This layout will allocate these extra pixels to 1 or more components depending of the property you set for the layout manager.

Also using the `Relative Layout` there will be no need to add a Border to each component. You can just set the "gap property" to leave 1 pixel between each component. The background of the parent panel will then show through.

Edit:

The basic code would be:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.Y_AXIS);
rl.setFill( true ); // to fill horizontal width
rl.setGap( 1 ); // so you don't need the border
somePanel.setLayout( rl );
```

Then in the loop:

```
somePanel.add(someComponent, new Float(1.0f));
```

Comment: A big thank you for this answer! The answer make sense for me... But my problem is, that I'm not really good in the GUI programming and i found not really much about this "relativeLayout" in the web. Can you help me with a little example? Is the relative Layout an external Class that I've add to my project? I hope you can help me more...

Comment: @Waldi, Yes it is an external class that you need to download from the link I proved you.

Comment: Again: A **BIG** thank you! You solved my 3 Day-Problem! With your little example I've understood the use of the relative Layout. Really, thank you! Exist in stackoverflow a rating system? I want like your profile...

Comment: But i have one more problem: How can I use this Relative Layout in a Border Layout? In my case i want use this Relative Layout inside of a Panel which is at the BorderLayout.CENTER position. If I set the Panels inside that, the Relative Layout doesnt work anymore... Can you help me please ones more?

Comment: Of course you can add a panel using the RelativeLayout to a panel using the BorderLayout. This is exactly the situation you have in your demo program. Just change the BoxLayout to the RelativeLayout as I suggested in my answer. The problem is not with the RelativeLayout, but your application code. If you want the panel using the RelativeLayout to resize automatically vertically, then the parent panel must also resize vertically and that is a good reason to add the panel to the CENTER of a BorderLayout because that panel will resize both vertically and horizontally.